# Continue getting data in background mode

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am getting data from server and show percentage to user. But when I click to phone home button (I mean my app in background mode. Not kill it) process stops. When I open app again it is continue.
What should I do to continue getting data in background mode?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/scenes/preparing_your_ui_to_run_in_the_background/extending_your_app_s_background_execution_time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below function, it will let your operation run in the background for 2-3 minutes.

```
  var aBackgroundTask: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier = UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier.invalid


func registerBackgroundTask() {
        aBackgroundTask = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask { [weak self] in
              self?.endBackgroundTask()
        }
        assert(callLoggingBackgroundTask != UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier.invalid)
    }


func endBackgroundTask() {
    print("Background task ended.")
    UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(convertToUIBackgroundTaskIdentifier(callLoggingBackgroundTask.rawValue))
    aBackgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier.invalid
}
```

Call function registerBackgroundTask() when operation starts and call this function endBackgroundTask() when operation finishes.

Answer (score 0):

As long as I know, unless your app is playing music or getting position update, the OS won't let your app working in the background for an endless period of time.

You can just tell the OS that your app needs some time to end a task, but generally you won't get more than one ore two minutes more.

Here there is a tutorial for background modes, I hope it can help...

https://www.raywenderlich.com/5817-background-modes-tutorial-getting-started

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have background modes checked in:

**YourApp -> Targets: YourApp -> Signing & Capabilities -> Check background modes**

In the **ViewDidLoad()**

```
let app = UIApplication.shared

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(applicationWillResignActive(notification:)), name: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification, object: app)

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(didBecomeActive(notification:)), name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: app)
```

Under the **viewDidLoad** you can add this

```
@objc func applicationWillResignActive(notification: NSNotification){
        print("Entered background")
    }

@objc func didBecomeActive(notification: NSNotification){
        print("Returned to application")
    }
```

So inside the **applicationWillResignActive** you can simply call the method to continue the reading.

I hope this is what you were looking for, else I can try to edit it as much as possible.

Comment: "applicationWillResignActive" is called when entering background, but it does not provide the ability to run endless tasks. It was created to stop any task running and saving stats or pausing games.

Comment: @Beppe In that case I'm sorry for the post.

I'm using that one to retrieve coordinates in the background and it works fine. Will still recieve coordinates after hours. :)

Comment: Don't be sorry, as I wrote in my answer you can get position updates or play music as long as you like, but you can't do other tasks for an endless period of time. The system will kill your app after some minutes. To be precise, "applicationWillResignActive" is called BEFORE entering background, even if you push two time home button and minimize you app WITHOUT actually entering background. Better of "applicationWillResignActive", it is "applicationDidEnterBackground"